# Backbone.js getting target attribute

Tags: javascript, html, json, backbone.js

I am trying to figure out why the value of e.target.getAttribute('data-text') is becoming null when I go from my HTML to my Backbone JS file.

HTML:

```
  <script type="text/template" id="lesson-template">
   <span id="lesson-title"><%= tracks[0].title %></span>
   <select class="sel">

    <% _.each(tracks, function(track) { %>
      <option value = "<%= track.text %>" data-text="<%= track.title %>"><%= track.title %></option>
      <% }); %> 
  </select>
  <p id="tracktext"><%=  tracks[0].text %></p>

</script>
```

JS:

```
window.LibraryLessonView = LessonView.extend({
events: {
    "change .sel " : "changeText"
},

changeText: function(e) {
alert(e.target.getAttribute('data-text')); //I am getting a null value here!
document.getElementById("lesson-title").innerHTML= e.target.getAttribute('data-text'); //I am getting a null value here as well
document.getElementById("tracktext").innerHTML= e.target.value;

}
```

Any clarification or help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change event will be fired on the `<select>`, not on the `<option>`, but your data attributes are on the `<option>`s. You could dig through `$(e.currentTarget)` (the `<select>`) to find the appropriate `<option>` and then extract the data attributes from there or you could use what you already have.

I would have something like this in the template:

```
<select class="sel">
    <% _.each(tracks, function(track) { %>
        <option value="<%= track.id %>"><%= track.title %></option>
    <% }); %> 
</select>
```

No data attributes at all, just a unique track identifier as the `<option>`'s value. Then when the change event is triggered, you can grab the track ID with:

```
var id = $(e.currentTarget).val(); // or $(e.target).val() but currentTarget is a bit safer
```

You should have the track list attached to your view as `this.collection` so now you can use [`get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get) to grab the model out of the collection:

```
var track = this.collection.get(id);
```

If you don't have `id`s on your models then you could use the [`cid`s](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid) that Backbone will create or something else that is unique and [`findWhere`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere) instead of `get`.

Now that you have the `track` model in hand, you can pull out the values you want in the usual way:

```
this.$('#lesson-title').html(track.get('title'));
this.$('#tracktext').html(track.get('text'));
```

Note that I've switch to [`this.$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar), that's a Backbone view function that is equivalent to [`this.$el.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), localizing your selectors to your view is a good habit.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Jas6c/

Comment: Using your javascript code, if I were to say var Tracks = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Track, url:link to some JSON file}); I am creating a collection of tracks this way. How would I deal with the line var v = new LibraryLessonView({ collection: tracks });?

Comment: @Robs: I'm not sure what you're asking. You need to `var tracks = new Tracks` to create a collection instance and then `tracks.fetch()` to load the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap jQuery arround to get target.

```
$(e.target).attr('data-text');
```

Comment: This still passes a null for me for some reasons.